# Is there a way to disable rotation in QuickLook?

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut, quicklook

I've gotten very used to using Command-R in Finder to locate the original file behind an alias or symlink.

In recent versions of the OS, Apple has seen fit to remap the "Find Original" shortcut to Command-Option-Control-A, which I personally find very awkward.

I have a workflow where I often need to retrace an original file from a symlink, so I've used System Preferences to reinstate my beloved Command-R shortcut.

However, to my horror, when QuickLook is open, Command-R rotates an image. I can understand tying that functionality to an on-screen button, but I find it very unfortunate that Apple has chosen to map a write operation to a keyboard shortcut. I've already modified several files unintentionally, and some of those were on a backup volume. In my opinion, there should AT LEAST be some kind of confirmation dialogue so you don't unintentionally modify a file.

Is there any way to un-map the QuickLook command-R shortcut, so this doesn't happen again?

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you said, however, you can easily undo a rotation to a photo.

Comment: So I tried to edit the relevant binary (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/Image.qldisplay/Contents/MacOS/Image`) by dissembling it and editing the rotate function to exit immediately, however every time I do it seems that I get a certification error. Seems like Apple signed something and me changing it creates an error.

Comment: @JBis I really appreciate your efforts. The only other option I can think of is remapping the key to something more difficult to hit unintentionally (Command-Control-Option-Shift-Zero, for instance.) Since you seem to be more adept at analyzing the binary, is there any kind of string or "handle" in there that I could use in System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts to remap the keyboard shortcut for rotate? Thanks again!